# Slice method indexing issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, slice

I have a string as an input in the form; lets say "1,5;6,10". Now, I want to compare the number at position 1 and 3 .i.e.(1 & 6). Whichever one is largest the number right to it would be printed. In this case the number 10 would be printed as 1 < 6.

Let the input is,
const customer_demand ="1,5;6,10";

I want to procced with slice() method and separate 1 and 6 with:

```
const number1 = customer_demand.slice(0, 1); // 1

const number2 = customer_demand.slice(4, 5); // 6
```

and compare the resultants with if & else. But there may be a case when the third number is two digit like:

```
const customer_demand ="1,5;16,10";
```

my slice() method index would go offset. What can I do in this regard? I hope I have made myself clear, if not please leave a comment. Thanks

Comment: Does your input string have different seprators? ",",  ";", anything else?

Comment: @DmytroKrasnikov yes its like "a,b;c,d"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it's better to use `split`:

```js
const customer_demand ="1,5;16,10";

const number1 = customer_demand.split(";")[0].split(",")[0]; // 1

const number2 = customer_demand.split(";")[1].split(",")[0]; // 16
```

Also if you want them to be `Number`s don't forget to cast it using `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I was also considering to go with Split() earlier.  but hoe should I procced with printing the numbers on right of largest number?

Comment: @KamranShakeel I don't understand what you want. Please clarify your comment.

Comment: thanks man, I figured it out.. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution, use `split`. Here's an example

```js
const customer_demand ="1,5;16,10";
function parseNumbers(string){
  return string.split(";") //returns stuff like ["1,5", "16,10"]
  .map(axis=>
    axis.split(",") //["1", "5"]
    .map(n=>parseInt(n)) //[1,5]
  )
}

//example usage
const parsedDemand=parseNumbers(customer_demand)
const [number1,number2,number3,number4]=parsedDemand
console.log(parsedDemand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier and break up your strings into managable arrays. Here is an example of when you don't know how many sets of numbers to compare ahead of time.

```
const customer_demand ="1,5;16,10";
// the following should also work for data like: "1,3,4,7;1,44;100"
let answers = [];
customer_demand.split(";").forEach( set => {
  let setitems = set.split(",");
  let biggest = setitems.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(Number(a), Number(b));
  });
 answers.push(biggest)
});
// answers is now an array - each item is the biggest number of that set. In your example it would be [5,16]
```